# How to implement Quartz Exponential Backoff strategy?

Tags: java, quartz

Currently my quartz job is triggered in this way:

- When first schedule the job, the job will be triggered after 5
  mins.
- The job will be triggered 5 times, with the time interval 2
  mins.

So if I schedule my job at time1, the job will be executed at
`time1 + 5`, `time1 + 7`, `time1 + 9`, `time1 + 11`, `time1 + 13`

```
  private org.quartz.Trigger makeTrigger() {
    org.quartz.ScheduleBuilder<org.quartz.SimpleTrigger> scheduleBuilder =
        org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
            .withIntervalInMilliseconds(intervalMillis)
            .withRepeatCount(repeatCount);

    return org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
        .withIdentity(key.getLeft(), key.getRight())
        .usingJobData(new org.quartz.JobDataMap(jobData))
        .startAt(dateTimeHelper.toStandardDate(startDateTime))
        .withSchedule(scheduleBuilder)
        .build();
  }
```

But I need to let the job be less aggressive, so my question is how to set the triggers to have exponential time intervals? So that after I schedule the job at time1, the job will be executed at:
`time1 + 5`, `time1 + 7`, `time1 + 11`, `time1 + 19`, `time1 + 35`?

Should I reschedule the job every time the job is finished?

Comment: could you not calculate the values for a cron trigger, or multiple single jobs?